# Using same project with mutiple configuration projects in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, development-environment, iphone-developer-program

I am making an app for my 5 clients. The only difference is icons and webservices. I don't want to make 5 different separate apps with same source code. What i am thinking to do is that i create one source project which will have all GUI and source code and then create a separate project for each client which start the source project with new configurations. I have never done that in iOS. Is there any way to do it? Please guide me about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could make a library and import it in all your projects

Comment: and how to tell that which icons and webservices use in the liberary?

Comment: i think you need to set different target for this and accordingly you need to specify constants and icon and other images.

Comment: Do you mean different plist for every target?

Answer (score 0):

i think you could just use one project and 5 different targets: icons may be different for each target, and you could define different k_constant to get the current target when compiling, if needed, and for images or other media imported, you could just use 5 different png with the same name and import each of them only in one target, so when compiling only the correct one will be exported in bundle